# How to Execute If Statements to Create a List Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to execute this numpy code in tensor flow. The reason for this is because I want to make binary predictions in a customized way (not using a softmax) and use that in the loss for my network later. Output1 is what the network outputs, an array of size (1, batch_size). Here is the numpy code:

```
predictions = []
for j in range(batch_size):
    if output1[0, j] >= output2[0] and output1[0, j] <= output2[1]:
        predictions.append(1)
    else:
        predictions.append(0)
```

In Tensorflow, I have tried to do something like this, using `tf.cond` since I want to evaluate the value of the output of the network and do something based on that:

```
predictions = []
for j in range(batch_size):
    condResult = tf.cond(output1[0, j] >= output2[0], lambda: predictions.append(1), lambda: predictions.append(0))
    condResultFalse = tf.cond(output1[0, j] <= output2[1], lambda: predictions.append(1), lambda: predictions(0))
```

However, this has some problems. First, if both conditions are true, it will append 1 to the list twice, which I don't want. Second, it throws an error saying `ValueError: true_fn must have a return value.` Apparently, I must return a tensor, but I'm not sure how to do this since I just want to append to a list.

Any help in translating this to Tensorflow would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution would be to use logical functions directly, saying tf.less_equal, or '<=', as follow using broadcasting:
It's gonna be '1' where your condition is `True`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

output1 = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1, 200), dtype='float32')
output2 = tf.constant([0.1, 0.5], dtype='float32')

a = output2[0] <= output1[0]
b = output1[0] <= output2[1]
c = tf.cast(tf.logical_and(a, b), tf.int64)

init  = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
res = sess.run(c)

print res
```

Edit: Actually working with int64

Comment: Will this evaluate when it's building the graph? I'm not trying to do that, as output2 and output1 are outputs of the network, so I want to look at what their values are and then do something based on that. That's why I thought I had to use `tf.cond`. I tried your solution, and `c` is always 0 before the data gets sent through, so that leads me to believe it is evaluating this graph, not the actual value.

Comment: I know that output1 and output2 are outputs of a network, I put them as constants like this you have an example. `c` is actually a vector here, you get only a 0 ? That's weird. Are really output1 a (1, batch_size) and output2 a (2) size Tensors? You did not mention the dimension of output2 actually.

Comment: `Output1` is actually `(2, batch_size)`, but I only care about one at a time so I index it by `output1[0, j]`. `Output2` is of size [2]. What I printed was before any data was passed in, and it says `Tensor("Cast_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)`. I haven't run it with data yet, will do that soon and update. What is the point of using `tf.cond` if you can just do this then? Are they the same thing?

Comment: I have another problem now, and have posted an edit to the original question. Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I am not creating the list correctly? I do `predictions.append(0)` and then `tf.convert_to_tensor(predictions)`. Debugging this with TensorBoard, I don't see `predictions` in the graph, maybe that's why it's not linked to the result and can't compute gradients? Do you have any idea of how to do this correctly?

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this is close to the answer, but that didn't work for me.

```
predictions = []
for j in range(batch_size):
        condition = tf.less_equal(output1[0, j], output2[1])
        condition2 = tf.greater_equal(output1[0, j], output2[0])
        resultingCondition = tf.where(condition, True, False)
        resultingCondition2 = tf.where(condition2, True, False)
        finalResultingCondition = tf.cast(tf.logical_not(tf.logical_and(resultingCondition, resultingCondition2)), tf.float32)
        predictions.append(finalResultingCondition)
```

This will append `1` and `0` instead of `1` and `-1`.

Comment: Looping on your batch_size is quite time consuming, you should use broadcasting.

Comment: The solution I gave you is directly giving 'predictions' as a Tensor.

Comment: Ok, I will try that in a bit and let you know. When I tried your original solution it didn't work.